# Identify DataFrame index object where a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas

How do I get an index object from my DataFrame when a specific condition is met, say for a given column?

The following returns a `Series` object with `True/False` values where some condition in the `foo` column of `my_dataframe` is  met:

```
true_entries = my_dataframe['foo'].apply(my_lambda_function) == True
```

But what I would like to get is an `index` object corresponding to those entries.

How do I do this?

As an example of an application, I would like to drop rows in my dataframe where that condition is met.

## Update:

I tried the suggestion from @DSM to drop entries (rows) from my dataframe, but the following command:

```
indices_to_drop = my_df.index[my_df['foo'].apply(my_lambda_function) == True]
my_df.drop(indices_to_drop)
```

returns:

```
DeprecationWarning: height has been deprecated
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want an `Index` corresponding to the true values, you can use the boolean `Series` as a slice on `df.index`:

```
>>> df
    A  B
0  10 -5
1  20 -2
2  30  1
3  40  4
4  50  7
>>> df["B"].apply(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
>>> df.index[df["B"].apply(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)]
Int64Index([1, 3], dtype=int64)
```

But if you only want to get rid of rows where that condition is met, you don't need to construct an explicit index at all.  You can simply keep the ones where the condition *isn't* met:

```
>>> df[~df["B"].apply(lambda x: x % 2 == 0)]
    A  B
0  10 -5
2  30  1
4  50  7
```

Comment: Thanks. The odd thing is that if I use that index object to drop rows from my dataframe I get: `/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config.py:570: DeprecationWarning: height has been deprecated.`. This is with the latest stable version of Pandas (0.12.0 from two days ago). I updated the OP.